# Integral $\int\frac{\sin2x}{1+x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\dfrac{\sin\;2x}{1+x^2}\;dx$$

**My approach:**

First of all I can try expanding $\sin \;2x$.

Which gives us,

$$\int\frac{2 \sin(x) \cos(x)}{1+x^2}\;dx$$

Then I can assume something like(probably flawed):

Let $\sin(x)=u$, thus, $\cos(x)dx=du$. Then, the integral would become,

$$\int\dfrac{u\;}{1+(\sin^{-1}\;u)^2}\;du$$.

---

I am not able to think the forward step from here. Or probably I must use other methods of integration(not sure)....Is there any mistakes in my above approach? If yes, where? And if not, what would be the forward step?

Comment: Do you expect there to be a nice answer? Remember, not all integrals have one! This is what WolframAlpha gives for your integral (it is not expressed in terms of elementary functions): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+of+sin%282x%29%2F%281+%2B+x%5E2%29.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth that's overly complicated....

Comment: So basically, you shouldn't expect there to exist a simple answer to your integral.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I expect a simple approach, complex answer is fine.

Comment: As Minus One-Twelfth points out, there is no simple approach here. It is not a matter of "no one has thought of it before", but rather "we can prove that there is no simple approach".

Answer (score 2):

let $I(t)=\int_0^x \frac{sin(tx)}{1+x^2},
     I'(t)=\int_0^x \frac{cos(tx)t}{1+x^2},
     I''(t)=\int_0^x \frac{-sin(tx)t^2}{1+x^2}$
which yields the equation if, we use integration by parts
$-I(t)t^2+\int_0^x 2tI(t)\frac{dt}{dx}dx = I''(t) -(1)$
further differentiating w.r.t t gives us $I'''(t)=-t^2I'(t)$

which means $I'(t)=A1cos(λt^2)+A2sin(λt^2)$

and I'(t) doesn't have an elementary antiderivative.

Answer (score -1):

[$$\int \frac{ \sin(2 x)}{(1 + x^2)} dx = \frac {((e^4 - 1) \,\mathrm Ci(2 i - 2 x) + (e^4 - 1) \,\mathrm (2 x + 2 i) + i (1 + e^4) (\mathrm Si(2 i - 2 x) + \mathrm Si(2 x + 2 i)))}{(4 e^2)} + C$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%20%28sin%202x%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%20dx)